# Setting the color of an HTML element using an index and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am designing a web application for handling various requests to a management team. I have these requests display in tables grouped by the type of request. Initially every request is given a red button since by default requests have not been completed. I am trying to figure out how I can change the color of a specific request's button once it has been marked as completed. Below is my Jquery code:

```
<script>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['index']) and $_SESSION['complete'] == 'internal'){
    echo "var index = '{$_SESSION['index']}';";
    unset($_SESSION['index']);
    unset($_SESSION['complete']);
    echo "$( '.complete:eq(index)' ).css('background','green')";
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['index']) and $_SESSION['complete'] == 'client'){
    echo "var index = '{$_SESSION['index']}';";
    unset($_SESSION['index']);
    unset($_SESSION['complete']);
    echo "$( '.client_comp:eq(index)' ).css('background','green')";
}
?>
</script>
```

By pressing a button you are sent to a page that displays all of the relevant request information. This is done by using another bit of jquery code to store the index of that class of button in a PHP session variable and then using that index to determine which request to load from the database. This page has a complete button that returns to the page with the tables and passes the index and the type of request that was completed back to that page. What my above code is attempting to do is set the color of that specific button using it's type and index. At this point in time everything works as expected except for the color change. I have searched and not been able to find a problem like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `echo "$('.complete').eq(index).css('background','green');";`

Comment: @LShetty Nothing changed

Comment: Look at the page source and see what's the output been?

Comment: The page source is not affected by later DOM modifications - the OP won't see anything there unless of course you meant for the OP to look at the output JS file.

Comment: I just checked the page source and noticed that for some reason the <script> tags have nothing between them but everything else is fine. Any idea what could be the cause of this? edit:could it be the php giving it trouble?

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand I'd asked him to look at the generated source!

Comment: @spencer most probably because PHP parses anything that starts with $ as variables (at least within `""`). Change your `$` to `jQuery` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @LShetty That didn't make a difference. I'm thinking my issue may be var index not actually seeing the session as a php session variable.

Comment: @spencer that's why I asked you to look at the page source and see what the index is set to.

Comment: @LShetty Sorry about the delay, I just had jquery write out the index after setting it and the value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need js variable. 
Can you try this.

```
<script>
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['index']) && $_SESSION['complete'] == 'internal'){
        echo "$( '.complete:eq(".$_SESSION['index'].")' ).css('background','green')";
    }
    elseif(isset($_SESSION['index']) && $_SESSION['complete'] == 'client'){
        echo "$( '.client_comp:eq(".$_SESSION['index'].")' ).css('background','green')";
    }
    unset($_SESSION['index'],$_SESSION['complete']);
?>
</script>
```